# Installation failed. One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation

Tags: java, wso2, maven-3, wso2-iot

My System is Linux Mint  SERENA;
On attemt to build the repository https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/releases/tag/v1.0.0-alpha

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T12:57:37+01:00)
Maven home: /home/caleb/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-53-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Comand issued : `mvn clean install`

error Log  :

```
  `Installing carbon.product.id 4.4.11.
Installation failed.
One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation.
Application failed, log file location: /media/caleb/DATA/REPOS/java/mvn/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-p2-runtime/0.13.0/eclipse/configuration/1502873665554.log

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Parent .................................. SUCCESS [  1.205 s]
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Broker Parent ........................... SUCCESS [  0.033 s]
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Broker - P2 Profile Gen ................. SUCCESS [ 20.512 s]
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Broker - Product Distribution ........... SUCCESS [ 35.205 s]
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Core Parent ............................. SUCCESS [  0.016 s]
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Core - Tools ............................ SUCCESS [  0.013 s]
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Device Type Archetype ................... SUCCESS [  1.954 s]
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Core - UI Styles ........................ SUCCESS [  0.884 s]
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Core - Server UI Features ............... SUCCESS [  0.032 s]
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Core - Server Styles Feature ............ SUCCESS [  0.095 s]
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Core - P2 Profile Gen ................... FAILURE [ 39.359 s]
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Core - Distribution ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Analytics Parent ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Analytics - P2 Profile Gen .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Analytics - Product Distribution ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Distribution Parent ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] >WSO2 IoT - Integration Tests ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Integration Test Artifacts .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 IoT Server - Integration Test Common .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Integration Test Common Web UI Pages .... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 IoT - Integration Test UI Module .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:40 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-16T09:54:27+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 59M/419M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5.4:materialize-product (p2-profile-generation-http-gateway-profile) on project wso2iot-core-profile-gen: Cannot generate P2 metadata: P2 publisher return code was 13 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :wso2iot-core-profile-gen
`
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated to build the product Successfully

Answer (score 2):

One you are trying is a very old tag, Would you please be able to try [this](https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/releases/tag/v3.1.0). This is the latest release tag of the WSO2 IoT 3.1.0

Comment: Same Error    Installing carbon.product.id 4.4.14.
Installation failed.One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation.

Application failed, log file location: /media/caleb/DATA/REPOS/java/mvn/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-p2-runtime/0.13.0/eclipse/configuration/1502893364759.log

Comment: This error is thrown because of the certificates are not trusted by the jvm. Try Downloading a fresh jdk and replacing the all the certificates in the installation folder.

Comment: Geeth I figured, uninstalled the default, jdk, downloaded a new one, and still had thesame error

Answer (score 2):

This error comes due to a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=309059) in the Equinox framework. According to the bug, latest Oracle VMs does not trust the certificates. As the solution, you can either download a fresh JDK and replace the current JDK or replace all the certificates in the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security`.

Comment: Madawa, Can I get the certificates I am to replace with, Or your version of JDK that works fine? I would be greatful

Answer (score 0):

Well I Un-installed everything, reinstalled maven , then downloaded a fresh jdk-netbeans file, installed, and everything ran fine to the End, thanks for the Input geeth and Madawa