# wso2am 21.0u14 building from source - One or more certificates rejected

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, p2

Trying to rebuild wso2am-2.1.0-update14 from the [source](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v2.1.0-update14) to fix an issue

(moving to newer version may be troublesome because of some customizations made)

building we get an exception

```
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - P2 Profile Generation ........... FAILURE [ 34.790 s]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5.4:materialize-product (creating-gateway-manager-profile) on project am-p2-profile: Cannot generate P2 metadata: P2 publisher return code was 13 -> [Help 1]

Failed build step is [INFO] --- carbon-p2-plugin:1.5.4:materialize-product (creating-gateway-manager-profile) @ am-p2-profile ---

[INFO] Command line:
        /bin/sh -c cd /home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product && /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-p2-runtime/0.13.0/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110725-1610.jar -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -metadataRepository file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -artifactRepository file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -installIU carbon.product.id -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true -profile gateway-manager -bundlepool file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.24/repository/components -shared file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.24/repository/components/p2 -destination file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.24/repository/components/gateway-manager -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86 -roaming
Installing carbon.product.id 4.4.24.
Installation failed.
One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation.
```

P2 logfile:

```
cat /home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-p2-runtime/0.13.0/eclipse/configuration/1543067992663.log
!SESSION 2018-11-24 13:59:52.546 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_192
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -metadataRepository file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -artifactRepository file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -installIU carbon.product.id -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true -profile gateway-manager -bundlepool file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.24/repository/components -shared file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.24/repository/components/p2 -destination file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.24/repository/components/gateway-manager -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86 -roaming
Command-line arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -metadataRepository file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -artifactRepository file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -installIU carbon.product.id -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true -profile gateway-manager -bundlepool file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.24/repository/components -shared file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.24/repository/components/p2 -destination file:/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.24/repository/components/gateway-manager -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86 -roaming

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 8 0 2018-11-24 13:59:55.314
!MESSAGE One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation.
```

Checking the destination `/home/ec2-user/dev2/product-apim-2.1.0-update14/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.24/repository/components/gateway-manager` doesn't exist

Anything I need to setup before building the distribution?

Edit:

reading another post [Installation failed. One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709327/installation-failed-one-or-more-certificates-rejected-cannot-proceed-with-inst)  seems a certificate is really not trusted.

I am building the release with OpenJDK 1.8.0_192 Corretto. Do I need to import any certificate somewhere? (importing the wso2carbon certificate did not help either)

Answer (score 0):

Seems using the Oracle JDK solved the issue itself. Though I don't really understand cause of this issue (what certificate is not trusted by what component)